# Estimate number of bad actors

Tags: sampling, expected-value

This might be a silly question, but it's got me stumped. I am trying to estimate the number of bad actors in a system.

Let's suppose we have 100 users, and some percentage of them are bad actors. In our system, the users are generating clips, say everyone on average generates 100 clips. The bad actors will, some percentage of the time, generate a bad clip. I want to figure out how many bad actors there are.

What would be the most efficient approach for sampling clips from our database to estimate how many bad actors there are? Can I randomly sample 100 clips and figure out the percentage of bad actors?

---

I have tried this problem a couple of times, and I keep getting tripped up by the fact that you don't know the distribution of clips a bad actor will generate. I'm not sure how to overcome that and generate an accurate estimate through sampling. Do you first need to find bad actors, and calculate the percentage of bad clips they might generate?

Comment: Your problem is underspecified: you can never 'know' how many bad actors there are without checking every clip of every user, so you need some probability bound on how certain you want to be. Is someone a bad actor as soon as they generate a single bad clip?

Comment: I think it is important to know whose clips you sample. If you put all the 100 clips of the 100 users into a big jar and draw randomly 100, they might be correlated and this might mess up your estimation. My idea is: define a cutoff in the number of bad clips to be a bad actor and just count how many on average are there to get a point estimate (you would get some kind of binomial distribution that way where n = 100 and the probability is to be determined by your cutoff). To find such a cutoff, maybe look at ROC curves? These are just suggestions of course, I'm happy to hear other opinions.

Comment: Yeah. A single bad clip counts someone as a bad actor. And you do know whose clip you sample.

Comment: Although the question is underspecified, I don't think that makes it unanswerable. My answer shows the unidentifiability of the problem without strong priors or more assumptions.

Comment: Could the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) be seen as inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out last night. Let's suppose that a bad actor creates bad clips a reasonable percentage of the time (say something like 5% to 50% of the time). If we can define the distribution like that, then the problem becomes simple.

We can just sample 100 random users and sample 100 clips for each user. I can be fairly certain that if a bad actor is acting reasonably within 100 clips, I'll most like be able to determine if someone is a bad or good actor.

With that in mind, I can figure out the percentage of bad actors from the 100 users I randomly sampled. That solves the problem!

Thanks, everyone!

---

p.s. I know the numbers I used are of a different magnitude than the ones I originally posted.

Comment: Might want to look at the confidence interval for a binomial proportion. 100/100 can be generated by a system that is 98% accurate. It doesn’t happen all the time, but it does happen. There’s a whole science around sampling. Entire textbooks.

Comment: I agree with @EngrStudent. Though your intuition is somewhat helpful, you have to be very careful with how you go about this. I have provided an answer based on Bayesian analysis that uses prior information (like your statement about $5$-$50$\% of the time) to give a range of reasonable values. Does this approach not work for you? Do you have any questions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's formalize the approach discussed in your answer. You're going to sample $n$ users $(i=1,2,\ldots, n)$. A sampled user is a bad actor with probability $p$, which is the overall proportion of bad actors (the thing you want to know). Let's model this with a Bernoulli RV, where $x_i=1$ for a bad actor and $x_i=0$ otherwise.
$$x_i \sim \text{Bern}(p), i=1,2,\ldots, n$$

Now, for user $i$, suppose you sample $m_i$ *clips* for that user. If we're dealing with a bad actor, then a bad clip will be generated with probability $\theta_1$. If the user is a good actor, then they generate bad clips with probability $\theta_0$ (which may be zero).
$$y_{ij} |x_i \sim \text{Bern}\left(\theta_{x_i}\right), j=1,2,\ldots, m_i$$

Finally, let's write out the log-likelihood function which will be useful for inference.
$$\ell(p, \theta_1, \theta_2 | {\bf x}, {\bf y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}\left\{y_{ij}\log \theta_{x_i} + (1-y_{ij})\log (1-\theta_{x_i}) + x_i \log p + (1-x_i)\log(1-p)\right\}$$

---

#### Identifiability

Without making some strong assumptions about the probabilities $p$, $\theta_0$, and $\theta_1$, you are going to have a tough time distinguishing between large $p$ and large $\theta_1$. For example,
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i} y_{ij}$$
is the total number of bad clips in your sample and
\begin{aligned}
E(T) &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i} E(y_{ij}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i} p \theta_1 + (1-p)\theta_0.
\end{aligned}
So if $\theta_0=0$ (for instance) then it is hard to tell whether $p$ or $\theta_1$ is driving the bad clips.

#### Bayesian Inference

Let us specify the following prior distributions
\begin{aligned}
p &\sim \text{Beta}(1, 1) \\
\theta_0 &\sim \text{Beta}(1, 100) \\
\theta_1 &\sim \text{Beta}(4, 16).
\end{aligned}
In these choices, we are specifying (i) a reasonably uninformative prior for $p$, (ii) a belief that good-actors rarely produce bad clips, (iii) a belief that bad-actors generate bad clips between 3.7% and 46.8% of the time (with high probability, e.g., 0.99). Now we can apply a standard Bayesian inference algorithm, such as adaptive MCMC.

#### R Code

Here's some R code, complete with synthetic data to try this out. I am using the `MHadaptive` R package for MCMC. For the code to work well, I am transforming the variables from a $(0, 1)$ scale to a $(-\infty, \infty)$ scale. This change of variables requires the addition of a Jacobian in the log posterior evaluation.

```
set.seed(123124908)
# True values
n     <- 50
mi    <- rep(20, n)
p     <- 0.1
theta <- c(0.001, 0.25)

# Simulate data
x <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
y <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=max(mi))
for(i in 1:n){
  y[i,1:mi[i]] <- rbinom(mi[i], 1, theta[1+x[i]])
}

log_likelihood <- function(param, x, y){
  n <- length(x)
  res <- 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    mi <- ncol(y) - length(which(is.na(y[i,])))
    for(j in 1:mi){
      res <- res + y[i,j]*log(param[2+x[i]]) 
      res <- res + (1-y[i,j])*log(1 - param[2+x[i]])
      res <- res + x[i]*log(param[1])
      res <- res + (1-x[i])*log(1 - param[1])
    }
  }
  return(res)
}

log_post <- function(param, x, y){
  # Convert parameters to (0, 1) scale
  p1 <- exp(param[1]) / (1 + exp(param[1]))
  p2 <- exp(param[2]) / (1 + exp(param[2])) #theta0
  p3 <- exp(param[3]) / (1 + exp(param[3])) #theta1
  
  # Calculate the Jacobian terms
  jacobian_term <- sum(log(p1 * (1 - p1)) + 
                         log(p2 * (1 - p2)) + 
                         log(p3 * (1 - p3)))
  
  # Calculate the log posterior with Jacobian correction
  res <- log_likelihood(c(p1, p2, p3), x, y)
  res <- res + dbeta(p1, 1, 1, log=TRUE)
  res <- res + dbeta(p2, 1, 100, log=TRUE)
  res <- res + dbeta(p3, 4, 16, log=TRUE)
  res <- res - jacobian_term  # Subtract Jacobian term
  
  return(res)
}

mcmc <- MHadaptive::Metro_Hastings(log_post, 
                                   pars=c(0.5, 0.000999, 0.2),
                                   prop_sigma=diag(rep(0.05, 3)),
                                   x=x, y=y)  

# Convert parameters to (0, 1) scale
param <- exp(mcmc$trace)/(1+exp(mcmc$trace)) + rnorm(length(param), 0, 1e-9)
# Make plot
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(param[,1], main="posterior for p", 
     xlim=range(c(p, param[,1])))
abline(v=p, lwd=2, col='orange', lty=3)

hist(param[,2], main="posterior for theta0", 
     xlim=range(c(theta[1], param[,2])))
abline(v=theta[1], lwd=2, col='orange', lty=3)

hist(param[,3], main="posterior for theta1", 
     xlim=range(c(theta[2], param[,3])))
abline(v=theta[2], lwd=2, col='orange', lty=3)
```

---

#### Results

How did we do? We did... alright? It looks like we correctly captured $\theta_1$ but we failed to capture the true value for $\theta_0$ or $p$. This shows the importance of having accurate priors! Although with more data, perhaps the situation will be improved.

[image: Posteriors for parameters]